# Replacing comma's by dots in floats using regular expressions

Tags: regex, floating-point, replace, batch-processing

In a large data file I would like to replace the comma by a dot in each floating point number.

56,66 should become 55.66 and so on.

The file contains many other comma's that should be left untouched.
The floating point numbers (and only those) should be changed.

What might be relevant info:

- There are never more than 3 digits before the comma (0, 1, 2 and 3 all occur though)
- There are never more than 2 digits behind the comma (0, 1 and 2 all occur though)

I can fire the regex in Notepad++ or Eclipse, that does not matter for me.

Comment: wait... from your description, it could be zero digit before **and** after the comma?? how can it be?

Comment: _There are never more than 2 digits behind the comma (0, 1 and 2 all occur though)_ So numbers like for example `23,` can occur too (doesn't make sense imho)? In what other context do you have commas?

Comment: @Simon also this `You know what,5 girls came to my party last nite` if there was no space after the comma... :)

Comment: It actually was a question to the OP ;)

Comment: Sorry guys you are absolutely right to point out that numbers like "23," don't exist. What I wanted to say is that the columns that contain the numbers can contain occurrences like 1,1 1,23 5,78 123,01 84,2 but indeed also plain integers like 1 11 or 111 that should also be left untouched. Zero digits before and after the comma, of course, also do not occur as these would not be numbers right :) Thanks Kent for the correct answer, it worked!

Comment: @Simon: I am converting the CSV file to a large SQL batch file, and the comma's are used as column separators in the queries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

just replace `(\d),(\d)` with `\1.\2`

don't have notepad++. in eclipse it worked.